# .htaccess Deny From All - IPv6 & Domains Not Allowing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security

I'm trying to set up where I can deny all IPs and allow only certain of them in. But the only thing that is working is IP4s and not either IPv6 or domains.

Please let me know if I'm missing something. It doesn't seem to work no matter what permutation.

---

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 67.93.23.3
allow from 127.133.23.33
allow from 2632:336:3639:2b30:b347:33d4:f135:f313
allow from domain.com
```

---

```
<RequireAll>
    Require all denied
    Require ip 64.91.24.3
    Require ip 2442:346:8355:8fa0:1110:3f47:198f:e80d
</RequireAll>
```

Comment: Are you positive the requests are coming from that address? In your apache error log you should see something like:  [authz_core:error] [pid 29430] [client -the ip address-] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: .....

Comment: I actually don't see any error logs for that?

Comment: More Information: Server Version: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4

Comment: It would be unusual for Apache not to log these denials. You have looked in the error log, but don't see the denials? Or you can't find the log file?

Answer (score 4):

```
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from ip
```

is deprecated.

Use

```
    Require ip ip.address
```

instead.

[Reference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html).

Comment: Using this, how do I block, all and allow specific IP6 Address. Because I do this and it doesn't work.

Comment: `<RequireAll> 
    Require all denied
    Require ip 63.91.223.3
    Require ip 2632:333: (Range)
</RequireAll>` <- This doesn't work.

Comment: <RequireAny>
        Require ip 64.91.24.3
        Require ip 2442:346:8355:8fa0:1110:3f47:198f:e80d
</RequireAny>